# Auto expand the treeview (hierarchy)

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

EDIT:

After looking at the developer console I found that its driving the two CSS class
`showContacts` & `hideContacts`

How can I auto-expand the treeview as soon as it clicks on the parent record?
so I have a parent and a child so when the Parent record is selected I want the child record to be expanded.

Here is what its doing:

[image]

I want to have like as shown below, when click on the radiobutton I want that to be expanded:

[image]

VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="vfp_bom_Controller" showheader="true">

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock id="accountList" title="Available Accounts" >

        <style type="text/css">
            .showContacts {
                background: transparent url('/img/alohaSkin/twisty_sprite.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
            }
            .hideContacts {
                background: transparent url('/img/alohaSkin/twisty_sprite.png') 0 -11px no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
<div id="InnternalDiv" style="overflow:auto;height:350px;" >
        <!-- first grid -->
       <apex:pageblocktable id="accountList" value="{!AllAccounts}" var="acc">
            <apex:column headervalue="Set as Primary">                    
               <apex:actionsupport action="{!LoadAccountContactByAccountId}" event="onclick" rerender="selectedContactList">  
                <input type="radio" name="Account" />                    
                    <apex:param name="accountId" value="{!acc.Id}">
                </apex:param></apex:actionsupport>                            
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headervalue="AccountNumber">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.AccountNumber}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column> 
            <apex:column headervalue="Name">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Name}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column>  
            <apex:column headervalue="NumberOfEmployees">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.NumberOfEmployees}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column>  
            <apex:column headervalue="Site">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Site}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column>  
        </apex:pageblocktable>
</div>


    <!-- second grid -->
    <apex:pageblock id="selectedContactList"  title="{!IF(accountList != NULL && accountList.size > 0,'Selected Contact','There are no records selected')}">
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!accountList.size!=0}"> 
            <table id="tableAccount" class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="headerRow">
                        <th class="actionColumn">Action</th>
                        <th>Account Name</th>
                        <th>Industry</th>
                        <th>Billing Country</th>
                        <th>Createdby</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat id="repeatAccount" value="{!accountList}" var="item">
                        <apex:variable var="acc" value="{!item.oAccount}" />   
                            <tr id="{!$Component.repeatAccount}:account" class="dataRow">
                                <td class="actionColumn">
                                        <!--<apex:inputCheckbox id="selectAccountRow" value="{!item.IsSelected}"         
                                                            onclick="javascript:toggleSelectAll(this, '{!$Component.repeatAccount}');"/> -->

                                        <apex:inputCheckbox >
                                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!Selected}" onsubmit="checkAll(this)" rerender="Selected_PBS"/>
                                        </apex:inputCheckbox>  
                                </td>
                                <td class="dataCell">
                                    <apex:outputLink id="linkShowHide" value="javascript:toggleContactRow('{!$Component.repeatAccount}')">
                                            <img id="{!$Component.repeatAccount}:Img" src="/s.gif" class="showContacts" 
                                                    border="0" height="11px" width="11px" style="padding-right: 4px;"/>
                                        <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Name}" />
                                    </apex:outputLink>
                                </td>
                                    <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!acc.Industry}" /></td>
                                    <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!acc.billingcountry}" /></td>
                                    <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!acc.CreatedById}" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr id="{!$Component.repeatAccount}:Contact" class="dataRow" style="display:none;">
                                    <td colspan="100" style="padding:10px; padding-left: 45px;">
                                        <apex:pageBlock >
                                            <h2>Contacts Detail by Account</h2>


                                        <apex:outputPanel layout="none">                                            
                                            <table id="tableAccountContacts" class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr class="headerRow">
                                                        <th class="actionColumn">Action</th> 
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <th>Email</th>
                                                        <th>Phone</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <apex:repeat id="repeatAccountContacts" value="{!item.contactSet}" var="subitem">
                                                        <apex:variable value="{!subitem.oContact}" var="con" />
                                                        <tr class="dataRow">
                                                           <!--<td class="actionColumn">
                                                                <apex:inputCheckbox id="selectContactRow" styleclass="ContactCheckbox" value="{!subitem.IsSelected}"/>
                                                            </td>  -->

                                                            <td class="actionColumn">                                                               
                                                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!subitem.isSelected}" id="checkedone"> 
                                                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!Selected}" rerender="Selected_PBS"/>
                                                                </apex:inputCheckbox>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!con.Name}" /></td>
                                                            <td class="dataCell"><apex:inputText id="email" value="{!con.email}"/></td>
                                                            <td class="dataCell"><apex:inputText id="phone" value="{!con.phone}"/></td>
                                                        </tr> 
                                                    </apex:repeat>                                                     
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </apex:outputPanel></apex:pageBlock>  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </apex:repeat>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </apex:outputPanel> </apex:pageblock>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        function toggleContactRow(rowId) {
            try {
                var AccountImg = jQuery(document.getElementById(rowId + ":Img"));
                var ContactsRow = jQuery(document.getElementById(rowId + ":Contact"));
                if (AccountImg.hasClass("hideContacts")) {
                    AccountImg.attr("class", "showContacts");
                    ContactsRow.hide();
                }
                else {
                    AccountImg.attr("class", "hideContacts");
                    ContactsRow.show();
                }
            }
            catch (e) { alert(e); }
        }  

        function toggleSelectAll(elCheckbox, rowId) {
            try {
                var SelectAll = jQuery(elCheckbox);
                var ContactsRow = jQuery(document.getElementById(rowId + ":Contact"));
                ContactsRow.find(".ContactCheckbox").each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).prop("checked", SelectAll.is(":checked"));
                });
            }
            catch (e) { alert(e); }
        }

        function checkAll(cb)
        {
            var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++)
            {
                if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1)
                inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
            }
        }    
    </script>  


</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, the `showContacts` & `hideContacts` CSS classes are used primarily to display the image which indicates whether the tree is collapsed or expanded.

The original code which expands the tree structure is

```
<apex:outputLink id="linkShowHide" value="javascript:toggleContactRow('{!$Component.repeatAccount}')">
    <img id="{!$Component.repeatAccount}:Img" src="/s.gif" class="showContacts" border="0" height="11px" width="11px" style="padding-right: 4px;"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Name}" />
</apex:outputLink>`
```

So you should call this `javascript:toggleContactRow('{!$Component.repeatAccount}')` whenever the radio button is selected like

```
<apex:column headervalue="Set as Primary">                    
    <apex:actionsupport action="{!LoadAccountContactByAccountId}" event="onclick" rerender="selectedContactList" oncomplete="javascript:toggleContactRow('{!$Component.repeatAccount}')">  
    <input type="radio" name="Account" />                    
    <apex:param name="accountId" value="{!acc.Id}">
    </apex:param></apex:actionsupport>                            
</apex:column>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried and didn't work and the reason is that its `toggleContactRow` expecting `Id`, .. not sure how to handle